# VBA - Split cells and concatenate parts of

Tags: excel, vba

```
ActiveCell.Value = InStr(1, ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value, " Mrs ", 1)
LengthOfString = Len(ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value)

If (ActiveCell.Value > 1 And complete = 0) Then
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Mr " & Mid(ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value, 4, LengthOfString - (LengthOfString - ActiveCell.Value) - 4)
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Mrs " & Right(ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value, (LengthOfString - ActiveCell.Value - Len(" Mrs ") + 1))
    complete = 1
    'ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = LengthOfString - ActiveCell.Value - 1
End If
```

The above is one of the variations I have managed to write to split variations like the following;

```
Mr and Mrs Smith
Mr & Mrs Smith
Mr John Smith & Mrs Smith
Mr John Smith and Mrs Smith
```

...and so on.

The formula basically takes the "Mr", any first name, and the surname, and concatenates them in the next cell.

It has been working perfectly, but the issue I'm facing now is the variation of

```
Mr and Mrs Arlene Smith
```

I've tried a few different things but I can't seem to get this to work. Rather than pulling through to read "Mr Smith" and I get the results of "Mr Arlene Smith".

It does however, pull through "Mrs Arlene Smith" correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Dim test As String
test = "Mr and Mrs Arlene Smith"
    If InStr(test, "and") > 1 Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Trim(Split(test, "and")(0)) 'Mr part
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = Trim(Split(test, "and")(1)) 'Mrs part
    ElseIf InStr(test, "&") > 1 Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Trim(Split(test, "&")(0))
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = Trim(Split(test, "&")(1))
    End If
    If ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Mr" Then
        'If "Mr part" is only "Mr", take last word from "Mrs part" and concatenate it with "Mr"
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Mr " & Split(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value, " ")(UBound(Split(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value, " ")))
    End If
```

Be aware that it works only when the string has "and" or "&" in it and if the surname is always the last word.

Comment: It'll need a little editing, as it doesn't work absolutely 100% perfectly, but that is a massive help, so thank you :)

Comment: Great! If you think it helped you, please consider to mark this answer as "accepted", so other users could see this thread as closed :) https://stackoverflow.com/tour